# Uncaught Error: Leaflet must be loaded before the leaflet heatmap plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, loading

I want to create a heatmap using heatmapjs and leaflet. However, I am stuck at loading the Javascript files. The error in my console says about 1 out of 2 times:

```
leaflet-heatmap.js:23 Uncaught Error: Leaflet must be loaded before the leaflet heatmap plugin
    at leaflet-heatmap.js:23
    at leaflet-heatmap.js:28
```

So half of the time it does load correctly, but the other half not.

I tried using different options suggested in different threads, none worked.

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.setAttribute('src', '<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/heatmap.js');
        document.head.appendChild(myScript);

        myScript.onload = function() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js";
            script.async = true;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        };
    </script>
```

or

```
<script async src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script async src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script async src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
```

Comment: We'll, you are loading heatmap.js, and leaflet-heatmap.js, but are you actually loading leaflet.js? Take at a look at the documentation here: https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Comment: I am loading it, i forgot to add it in the code! Thread edited

Comment: try without the async attributes in the script tags, you cannot use that if you need the scripts to load in a certain order

Comment: I can't believe that actually did it... Thank you very much!

Comment: I've written up the answer from the comments to an actual answer, if it helps you, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script tags need to be loaded in a specific order. *leaflet.js* needs to be loaded first. If you use the *async* attribute on script tags, there is no guarantee in which order they are loaded. To fix your problem, omit the *async* attribute:

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
```